# ActionBar back button crash my app

Tags: android-actionbar

I have problem with my school project when I want to back to my `CurentCourseActivity` using back button form action bar I have NE

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.List `com.example.pingu.mylanguages.Language.getList()' on a null object reference at 
com.example.pingu.mylanguages.CurentCourseActivity.onCreate(CurentCourseActivity.java:37)`
```

While I use normal back button problem is not appear.
When we choose `Lesson` from `GridView` that makes a new activity. When we choose the back button from `ActionBar` then I have NE.

CourentCourseActivity:

```
public class CurentCourseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Language language;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("s","onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_curent_course);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState!=null){
           language = (Language) savedInstanceState.getSerializable("Lang");
            Log.d("xx","Coś ma");
        }

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            language = (Language) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Lang"); //Obtaining data
        }


        GridView grid = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        CurrentCourseAdapter adapter = new CurrentCourseAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_curent_course, language.getList());
        grid.setAdapter(adapter);

        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CurentCourseActivity.this,LessonActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Lesson",(Lesson)language.getList().get(i));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(language.getName());
    }

}
```

LessonActivity:

```
public class LessonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lesson);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
            Lesson lesson = (Lesson) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("Lesson");
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(lesson.getNamel());
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simplest then I expect. So I need to overide this button and do it as normal back button because ActrionBar back button destroy parent activity.

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {

case android.R.id.home:
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```